# Angular 6, get filtered data from GET http call to API, based on selected value, without pipes

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 6 and ASP.NET Core 2.0, built separately.  I have an HTTP GET call that returns a list of locations to a drop-down.  I would like to filter the TeacherName option/drop-down to only display the names (in the back end SQL database) equal to the location selected in the drop-down.
 The error in the browser says... **TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined**

So, I don't think the syntax is correct in the "filterTeachers" function, but it could be something else (?).  Can Angular do these types of client-side filtering without pipes?  Should it be done as a linq query instead in the back-end?

Here is update.component.html...

```
<div>
  <form>  
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="LogLocation-input">Select Your Location </label>
  <select type="text" id="LogLocation" name="LogLocation-input" [(ngModel)]="teacherLocInput" (ngModelChange)="basedOnLoc($event)" class="form-control"> 
<option *ngFor="let loc of teacherLocationsData" [value]="loc.location">
  {{ loc.location }}
</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="TeacherName-input">Enter Teacher Name </label>
  <select type="text" id="TeacherName" name="TeacherName-input" [(ngModel)]="loggingInfo.ClassTimesTeacherName" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let nam of filteredTeacherNames"> 
      {{ nam.name }}
    </option>  
  </select>
</div>


      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addOrUpdateLoggingRecord($event);">Save</button>

      <h2 *ngIf="!loggingInfo || loggingInfo.id === undefined">Add record</h2>

      <h2 *ngIf="loggingInfo && loggingInfo.id !== undefined">Update record (ID: )</h2>

  </form>
 </div>
```

Here is the update.component.ts...

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TimeService } from '../time.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-update',
  templateUrl: './update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update.component.css']
})
export class UpdateComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() loggingCreated = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() loggingInfo: any;
  public buttonText = 'Save';
  public teacherLocationsData: Array<any>;   
  public teacherNameData: Array<any>;
  public filteredTeacherNames: Array<any>;

  private _teacherLocInput: string;
  get teacherLocInput(): string {
    return this._teacherLocInput;
  }
  set teacherLocInput(value: string) {
  this._teacherLocInput = value;
  this.filteredTeacherNames = this.filterTeachers(value);
}

filterTeachers(teacherLocInput: string) {
  return this.teacherNameData.filter(teacher => teacher.location === this.teacherLocInput);
}


  constructor(private timeService: TimeService) { 
    this.clearAllInfo();
    timeService.getTeacherLocation().subscribe((importLocations: any) => this.teacherLocationsData = importLocations);   
 }

  ngOnInit() {
    // not sure if needed
    this.teacherNameData;

  }

basedOnLoc(val:any) {
  // not sure if this is calling API
this.customFunction(val);
}

// gets called on the change event of location selected
customFunction(val:any) {
  this.teacherLocInput = val; 
  this.timeService.getTeacherName().subscribe((importTeacherName: any) => this.teacherNameData = importTeacherName);  
}



  private clearAllInfo = function() {
    // Create an empty logging object
    this.loggingInfo = {
      id: undefined,
      date: '',
      ClassTimesStudentID: '',
      ClassTimesStudentName:'',
      ClassTimesSubjects: '',
      ClassTimesLogLocation: '',
      ClassTimesTeacherID: '',
      ClassTimesTeacherName: '',
      ClassTimesLogOff: '',
      timeInSeconds: 0,
      distanceInMeters: 0
    };
  };

  public addOrUpdateLoggingRecord = function(event) {
    this.loggingCreated.emit(this.loggingInfo);
    this.clearAllInfo();
    console.log(this.LoggingIfo);
  };


}
```

Here is new version using Angular Reactive Forms...

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TimeService } from '../time.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-update',
  templateUrl: './update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update.component.css']
})
export class UpdateComponent implements OnInit {
  timeLogForm: FormGroup;

  @Output() loggingCreated = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() loggingInfo: any;
  public buttonText = 'Save';

  public teacherLocationsData: Array<any>;
  public teacherNameData: Array<any>;
  public filteredTeacherNames: Array<any>;

  get filterTeachers() {
    return this.teacherNameData.filter(teacher => teacher.location === this.timeLogForm.controls.location.value);
  }
 constructor(private timeService: TimeService, private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    timeService.getTeacherLocation().subscribe((importLocations: any) => this.teacherLocationsData = importLocations);
    timeService.getTeacherName().subscribe((importTeacherName: any) => this.teacherNameData = importTeacherName);
  }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.timeLogForm = this.fb.group({
      id: null,

      ClassTimesLogLocation: null,
      ClassTimesTeacherName: null,

    });
  }
 public addOrUpdateLoggingRecord = function(event) {
    this.loggingCreated.emit(this.loggingInfo);
  };


}
```

Here is Reactive Forms template...

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="timeLogForm">
div class="form-group">
  <label for="LogLocation-input">Select Your Location </label>
  <select type="text" id="LogLocation" name="LogLocation-input" formGroupName="ClassTimesLogLocation" class="form-control"> 
<option *ngFor="let loc of teacherLocationsData" [value]="loc.location">
  {{ loc.location }}
</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="TeacherName-input">Enter Teacher Name </label>
  <select type="text" id="TeacherName" name="TeacherName-input" formGroupName="ClassTimesTeacherName" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let nam of filteredTeacherNames" [value]="nam.name" > 
      {{ nam.name }}
    </option>  
  </select>
</div>      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addOrUpdateLoggingRecord($event);">Save</button>

      <h2 *ngIf="!loggingInfo || loggingInfo.id === undefined">Add record</h2>

      <h2 *ngIf="loggingInfo && loggingInfo.id !== undefined">Update record (id: )</h2>

  </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think you should call `console.log()` to debug `basedOnLoc()` method. Otherwise you won't detect where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I think this is because you are setting the`teacherNameData` only when the ngModelChange event fires and the template is looking for the `filteredTeacherNames` which is assigned to `this.filterTeachers(value)`, i.e. calling the function and at that time `teacherNameData` is undefined

Comment: You can add `*ngIf` directive to look for `filteredTeacherNames` before iterating over it.

Comment: Thanks for the great advise here.  I removed the "basedOnLoc()" and custom function, and now the filter works great, so happy.  I'm going to try using reactive forms to see if I like format that better.

Comment: @Suryan if you don't mind, I have another question posted similar to this issue (you did such a great job helping me with) can you take a look?  I have 2 getter setters, and I think the 2nd is null because the function calls too soon.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132342/how-do-i-get-set-a-value-from-another-getter-setter-my-second-array-is-not-crea/54132527#54132527

Answer (score 0):

First off, a lot of the logic you have going on can be simplified with angular's ReactiveForms. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms This is honestly one of my favorite parts of angular. It makes the class the single source of truth for the form instead of the template. Anyway, on to your question. You can use a getter as the array to iterate over in `*ngFor`. It will run the method on change so it handles it for you.

in your .ts file:

```
get filterTeachers() {
  return this.teacherNameData.filter(teacher => teacher.location === this.teacherLocInput);
}
```

html:

```
<option *ngFor="let nam of filterTeachers"> 
  {{ nam.name }}
</option>
```

IF you're interested in ReactiveForms:

component.ts (of course missing a lot of the data you need that you already have):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'selector-name',
  styleUrls: ['selector-name.component.scss'],
  template: `something.html `
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  teacherLocationForm: FormGroup;

  get filterTeachers() {
    return this.teacherNameData.filter(teacher => teacher.location === this.teacherLocationForm.controls.location.value);
  }

  constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.teacherLocationForm = this.fb.group({
      location: null,
      teacher: null
    });
  }


}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="teacherLocationForm">  
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="LogLocation-input">Select Your Location </label>
  <select type="text" id="LogLocation" name="LogLocation-input" formGroupName="location" class="form-control"> 
<option *ngFor="let loc of teacherLocationsData" [value]="loc.location">
  {{ loc.location }}
</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="TeacherName-input">Enter Teacher Name </label>
  <select type="text" id="TeacherName" name="TeacherName-input" formGroupName="teacher" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let nam of filterTeachers"> 
      {{ nam.name }}
    </option>  
  </select>
</div>


      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addOrUpdateLoggingRecord($event);">Save</button>

      <h2 *ngIf="!loggingInfo || loggingInfo.id === undefined">Add record</h2>

      <h2 *ngIf="loggingInfo && loggingInfo.id !== undefined">Update record (ID: )</h2>

  </form>
```

Then your values are updated into that `teacherLocationForm` property. You can access them with `this.teacherLocationForm.value`. Form Groups are super powerful and hold the state of the form, errors, and are easily submitted.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Reactive Forms.  Pretty sure I should be using this instead.  I appreciate you adding the code too.  I've built a new version in Reactive Forms and updated my post with the new code.  I can't get the filter to work..?  Not sure how to send the filtered data to the "filteredTeacherNames" array, so I can access it in the template.  Please advise if you can. Thnx.

Comment: Instead of `<option *ngFor="let nam of filteredTeacherNames" [value]="nam.name" >` you should use your `get filterTeachers()`. It would look like this `<option *ngFor="let nam of filterTeachers" [value]="nam.name" >`

Comment: Made that change, and it's still not working.  Browser errors say...  "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined" and "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" hmmm.

Comment: this.timeLogForm.controls.location.value is giving you the value undefined error. I didn't look earlier at this, but in your buildForm() method you don't set location as a control so it's seeing it as undefined. I'm guessing you'll want to change that to this.timeLogForm.controls.ClassTimesLogLocation.value. As for the filter issue put an if statement in `get filterTeachers()` that checks for if the value has been set yet for `teacherNameData`. If it has, return what you currently have, otherwise, return an empty array. The problem is that it checks that filter before the value is set.