# How do I get/set a value from another getter/setter? My second array is not created, Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have two http GET API calls in the constructor.  The first one works great.  It has a getter/setter to filter the main array (studentNameData) to a filtered array (filteredName).  The second call is trying to do the same thing, by getting/setting the value of "ClassTimesLogLocation" from the first array (filteredName).
The main array on the second call (allStaff) is good, but the filtered array (filteredStaffName) is not getting created (?).  I have no errors in the code.  My console log shows no array, and I can't access the array in the html *ngFor...
 I've never made two getter/setters like this, is it set up wrong?  I feel like Angular can't get the value for the second filtered array quick enough, or something in the timing ..?

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">  
      <div class="row">

 <label for="name">Student ID</label>
             <input type="text" id="ClassTimesStudentID" 
name="ClassTimesStudentID" required [(ngModel)]="ClassTimesStudentID"
            class="form-control">

<div *ngFor="let nam of filteredName; let in = index" class="col-sm-6 form- 
   group">
          <label for="ClassTimesLogLocation-input">School Location </label>
          <input type="text" name="schoolNumber-{{in}}" 
[(ngModel)]="nam.schoolNumber" name="ClassTimesLogLocation"
            [(ngModel)]="ClassTimesLogLocation" class="form-control">

 <!-- this duplicat is for posting to DB -->
          <label for="ClassTimesLogLocation">hide</label>
          <input type="text" name="ClassTimesLogLocation" 
[(ngModel)]="nam.schoolNumber" [(ngModel)]="ClassTimesLogLocation"
            class="form-control">
        </div>

 <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label for="ClassTimesTeacherName-input">Select a Teacher </label>
        <select type="text" name="readStaffLastName" 
          [(ngModel)]="ClassTimesTeacherName" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let staff of filteredStaffName">
            {{ staff.readStaffLastName }}
        </option>    
        </select>
      <div> <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">{{ editMode ? 'Update' : 'Add' }}</button> <div>

      </div>  </div></form>
```

Here is component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
 import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
 import { DataStorageService } from 'src/app/shared/data-storage.service';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-logedit',
   templateUrl: './logedit.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./logedit.component.css'] })

 export class LogEditComponent implements OnInit {


  public studentNameData: Array<any>;
  public filteredName: Array<any>;
  public allStaff: Array<any>;
  public filteredStaffName: Array<any>;

  private _ClassTimesStudentID: any;
  get ClassTimesStudentID(): any {
   return this._ClassTimesStudentID; }

   set ClassTimesStudentID(value: any) {
     this._ClassTimesStudentID = value; 
    this.filteredName = this.filterStudent(value);
    console.log('filter student array ' + this.filteredName)
  }

  filterStudent(ClassTimesStudentID: any) {
return this.studentNameData.filter(name => name.studentIdother === this.ClassTimesStudentID);}

      private _ClassTimesLogLocation: any;
      get ClassTimesLogLocation(): any {
      return this._ClassTimesLogLocation; }

      set ClassTimesLogLocation(value: any) {
      this._ClassTimesLogLocation = value; 
      this.filteredStaffName = this.filterStaff(value);
      console.log('filter staff array ' + this.filteredStaffName)}

   filterStaff(ClassTimesLogLocation: any) {
     return this.allStaff.filter(loc => loc.readStaffLocationCode === 
  this.ClassTimesLogLocation);}


  constructor(private dataStorageService: DataStorageService,) {

    dataStorageService.getStudentDataAll().subscribe((importName: any) => 
    this.studentNameData = importName);
    dataStorageService.getStaff().subscribe((importStaff: any) => 
    this.allStaff = importStaff);
    console.log('call allStaff ' + this.allStaff);
   }

   ngOnInit() {}


  }
```

Here is data-storage.service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
 import 'rxjs/Rx';

 @Injectable()
 export class DataStorageService {
   private headers: HttpHeaders;
   private accessPointUrl: string = 'http://localhost:59673/api/ClassTimes';

   constructor(private http: HttpClient,
          private adminService: AdminService,
          private authService: AuthService) {
   this.headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; 
 charset=utf-8'}); }

 public getStaff() {
// calls ReadStaffsController, staff comes in filtered by job class
return this.http.get('http://localhost:59673/api/ReadStaffs', {headers: this.headers});
    }

  public getStudentDataAll() {
// calls ScheduleDemographicsController
return this.http.get('http://localhost:59673/api/ScheduleDemographics', {headers: this.headers});  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you tell that `filteredStaffName` is not created anywhere.

It is created inside `set ClassTimesLogLocation(value: any)`. But the thing is, this setter is never used in your code. That's why this property is always undefined.

Also, please remember to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I added more code, I apologize for the brevity.  I thought that this line...     `this.filteredStaffName = this.filterStaff(value);`   assigns the setter value to the array (filteredStaffName)?  Then I can access those values in the array.  (this is how the first getter/setter works)

Comment: @web.dev is correct, setter is never being called in your component and one more thing I don't think you will get the value here in this `console.log('call allStaff ' + this.allStaff);` line of code. It should be inside your subscribe function after setting the value of `this.allStaff`.